# Verifying Authenticode signed executables and DLLs using OpenSSL API

Tags: c, cryptography, openssl, rsa, authenticode

I have installed **openssl** and now the **rsa_test.c** is running fine. What I want to do is:

1. Open any exe or dll digital certificate. Extract the **Thumbprint** and **PublicKey**.
   The public key contains the **exponent** too (if you are familiar with ASN1 encoding).
2. Now I have already calculated **SHA-1** hash of the file and compared it to the MD field to find it correct. So now I want to pass the **Thumbprint**, **PublicKey->m** and **PublicKey->e** to **RSA_public_decrypt** function to calculate the decrypted **SHA-1** hash of the file.

What **Padding Algorithm** should I pass to the function? When I pass **RSA_NO_PADDING**, it decrypts but give me the 128-bytes long hash which is not at all correct. For all other padding algorithm options it returns the error of padding not found.

Would you please teach me or tell me the correct parameters to pass through the function with an example or good link to example?

Comment: nice question: I suggest also post you question at http://security.stackexchange.com/...

Comment: Could you just post such a 128 byte block decrypted RSA signature?

Comment: @WhozCraig- I did it manually as per the code given in RFC. But I have removed the corresponding regions as explained in Authenticode Documentation. The hash is correct as I verified it with the MD field of the certificate.

Comment: Good question: I think this is the most common problem encountered everyday by lots of coders who try using OpenSSL to verify the signature.

Comment: in man for RSA_public_decrypt it's stated: "This function does not handle the algorithmIdentifier specified in PKCS #1. When generating or verifying PKCS #1 signatures, rsa_sign(3) and rsa_verify(3) should be used."
If you still want to use the decrypt function (why?) be sure that you have correct endianness for both m, e, and the encrypted digest.

Comment: Also see Microsoft's [Windows Authenticode Portable Executable Signature Format](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/c/5/9c5b2167-8017-4bae-9fde-d599bac8184a/Authenticode_PE.docx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [PKCS7_verify](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/PKCS7_verify.html) function to verify the whole PKCS #7 signedData block.

You need two steps to completely verify the signature (see [Microsoft specs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/hardware/gg463183)):

1. Verify the integrity and identity of the PKCS #7 signature.
2. Calculate the Message Digest and compare it to the one specified in the signature.

Note that the digest is not limited to SHA-1 in the specs. The digest algorithm is contained in digestAlgorithm field in the signature.

Comment: I appreciate the advice but I do not want to verify it that way. I just want to decrypt the RSA-Encrypted Sha1 hash. Any ideas on that???

Comment: The question he asked and the answer you have given does not co-relate.

Comment: @Abhineet The answer is fine. It would certainly be a sensible way to approach the issue and it may be useful for the OP to see an alternative (possible better) solution.

Comment: @DuncanJones- Yeah the approach to verify is good. Its always better to do the complex verification process using some standard code and library. But why can't anybody provide the straight answer to this question. Even I tried googling it and searched everywhere but couldn't get any perfect solution. And now, even I am waiting for this question to be answered :-)

Comment: @Abhineet: PKCS7 signedData is the DER encoding of a relatively complex ASN.1 structure. You really, really, want to to use a PKCS7-aware function to do all the DER decoding needed. The only other answer would be "do all the painful DER decoding yourself to get to the signature bits and then apply the RSA_public_decrypt method".

Comment: @GregS- I have done all that. I have an ASN_Parser and a SHA1_Generator which I have written myself. I am trying to use the solution Rostislav Kondratenko provided. Any example or sample to use the PKCS7_Verify function?

Comment: @Abhineet: I haven't find any examples that may illustrate the whole process. The interface is pretty straightforward. You call like
int isVaild = PKCS7_verify(p7, trusted_certs, ca_store, NULL, NULL, 0); //or other combination of trusted_certs, ca_store and flags as appropriate in your case.
The PKCS7 structure is populated by p7=d2i_PKCS7_bio(in,NULL); certs collections by what's specific in your case. What part exactly is causing problems?

Comment: @RostislavKondratenko- Hey, this is not my question. Ask user1696837 to identify the problems. I am just following this question. :-D

Comment: +1 for eye-opening hint to use PKCS7_verify. @Abhineet- Though I am having difficulty in using PKCS7_verify but it is much more easier than using RSA_public_decrypt function.

Comment: @RostislavKondratenko- do you have any example up on your sleeves which you can post here showing how to pass the parameters and populate those structs and also the type of file the function would accept?

Comment: @user1696837 Unfortunately I have not. Never done this myself. There are examples on the web on how to read PKCS7, how to read certificate collection, but even in the OpenSSL example code they do not use PKCS7_verify function.

Comment: Let me try the PKCS7_verify function and if not succeded, will post the question regarding the usage of the function. @RostislavKondratenko- +1 for your efforts.

Comment: @user1696837 did you succeed with `PKCS7_verify`?

Comment: @jweyrich- No dude, am still struggling :-(